# Coordenada em mapa MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-5

Eu preciso mostrar um mapa para o usuário e permitir que ele escolha uma localidade.

Após escolher o local eu preciso retornar as coordenadas GPS(Latitude,Longitude)  para a action.

Qual a melhor forma de fazer isto?

Obs.: Pode ser usando javascript, jQuery ou algum componente free.

Comment: dê uma olhada neste tuto: http://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/Get-Latitude-and-Longitude-Location-Coordinates-using-Google-Maps-OnClick-event.aspx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Qualquer componente de mapas faz isso que voce quer. Escolha um, tente aplicar, e se não conseguir, mande uma pergunta, mostrando o que vc já fez. Assim podemos realmente ajudar.

- [Bing Maps Dev Center](https://www.bingmapsportal.com/)
- [Here Maps for Developers](https://developer.here.com/)
- [Google Maps API](https://developers.google.com/maps/)